# MS Access antiquated? Anything new in 2011?

Tags: ms-access

Our company has a database of 17,000 entries.  We have used MS Access for over 10 years for our various mailings.  Is there something new and better out there?  I'm not a techie, so keep in mind when answering.  Our problems with Access are: 
-no record of what was deleted, 
-will not turn up a name in a search if cap's or punctuation 
is not entered exactly, 
-is complicated for us to understand the de-duping process. 
- We'd like a more nimble program that we can access from more than one dedicated computer.

Answer (score 7):

The only applications I know of that are comparable to Access are FileMaker Pro, and the database component of the Open Office suite. FM Pro is a full-fledged product and gets good marks for ease of use from non-technical users, while Base is much less robust and is not nearly as easy for creating an application.

All of the answers recommending different databases really completely miss the point here -- the original question is about a data store and application builder, not just the data store.

To the specific problems:

#### PROBLEM 1: no record of what was deleted

This is a design error, not a flaw in Access. There is no database that really keeps a record of what's deleted unless someone programs logging of deleted data.

But backing up a bit, if you are asking this question it suggest that you've got people deleting things that shouldn't be deleted. There are two solutions:

1. regular backups. That would mean you could restore data from the last backup and likely recover most of the lost data. You need regular backups with any database, so this is not really something that is specific to Access.
2. design your database so records are never deleted, just marked deleted and then hidden in data entry forms and reports, etc. This is much more complicated, but is very often the preferred solution, as it preserves all the data.

### Problem #2: will not turn up a name in a search if cap's or punctuation is not entered exactly

There are two parts to this, one of which is understandable, and the other of which makes no sense.

1. punctuation -- databases are stupid. They can't tell that Mr. and Mister are the same thing, for instance. The solution to this is that for all data that needs to be entered in a regularized fashion, you use all possible methods to insure that the user can only enter valid choices. The most common control for this is a dropdown list (i.e., "combo box"), which limits the choices the user has to the ones offered in the list. It insures that all the data in the field conforms to a finite set of choices. There are other ways of maintaining data regularity and one of those involves normalization. That process avoids the issue of repeatedly storing, say, a company name in multiple records -- instead you'd store the companies in a different table and just link your records to a single company record (usually done with a combo box, too). There are other controls that can be used to help insure regularity of data entry, but that's the easiest.
2. capitalization -- this one makes no sense to me, as Access/Jet/ACE is completely case-insensitive. You'll have to explain more if you're looking for a solution to whatever problem you're encountering, as I can't conceive of a situation where you'd actually not find data because of differences in capitalization.

### Problem #3: is complicated for us to understand the de-duping process

De-duping is a complicated process, because it's almost impossible for the computer to figure out which record among the candidates is the best one to keep. So, you want to make sure your database is designed so that it is impossible to accidentally introduce duplicate records. Indexing can help with this in certain kinds of situations, but when mailing lists are involved, you're dealing with people data which is almost impossible to model in a way where you have a unique natural key that will allow you to eliminate duplicates (this, too, is a very complicated topic).

So, you basically have to have a data entry process that checks the new record against the existing data and informs the user if there's a duplicate (or near match). I do this all the time in my apps where the users enter people -- I use an unbound form where they type in the information that is the bare minimum to create a new record (usually some combination of lastname, firstname, company and email), and then I present a list of possible matches. I do strict and loose matching and rank by closeness of the match, with the closer matches at the top of the list.

Then the user has to decide if there's a match, and is offered the opportunity to create the duplicate anyway (it's possible to have two people with the same name at the same company, of course), or instead to abandon adding the new record and instead go to one the existing records that was presented as a possible duplicate.

This leaves it up to the user to read what's onscreen and make the decision about what is and isn't a duplicate. But it maximizes the possibility of the user knowing about the dupes and never accidentally creating a duplicate record.

### Problem #4: We'd like a more nimble program that we can access from more than one dedicated computer.

This one confuses me. Access is multi-user out of the box (and has been from the very beginning, nearly 20 years ago). There is no limitation whatsoever to a single computer. There are things you have to do to make it work, such as splitting your database into to parts, one part with just the data tables, and the other part with your forms and reports and such (and links to the data tables in the other file). Then you keep the back end data file on one of the computers that acts as a server, and give a copy of the front end (the reports, forms, etc.) to each user. This works very well, actually, and can easily support a couple of dozen users (or more, depending on what they are doing and how well your database is designed).

Basically, after all of this, I would tend to second @mwolfe02's answer, and agree with him that what you need is not a new database, but a database consultant who can design for you an application that will help you manage your mailing lists (and other needs) without you needing to get too deep into the weeds learning Access (or FileMaker or whatever). While it might seem more expensive up front, the end result should be a big productivity boost for all your users, as well as an application that will produce better output (because the data is cleaner and maintained better because of the improved data entry systems).

So, basically, you either need to spend money upfront on somebody with technical expertise who would design something that allows you to do better work (and more efficiently), or you need to invest time in upping your own technical skills. None of the alternatives to Access are going to resolve any of the issues you've raised without significant investment in interface design to further the goals you have (cleaner data, easier to find information, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of sounding snide, what you are really looking for is a **consultant**.

In the hands of a capable programmer, all of your issues with Access are easily handled.  The problems you are having are not the result of using the wrong tool, but using that tool less than optimally.

Actually, if you are not a techie then Access is already the best tool for you.  You will not find a more non-techie friendly way to build a data application from bottom to top.

That said, I'd say you have three options at this point:

1. Hire a competent database consultant to improve your application
2. Find commercial off-the-shelf (COTS) software that does what you need (I'm sure there are plenty of products to handle mailings; you'll need to research)
3. Learn about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [building proper MS Access applications](http://allenbrowne.com/Tips.html)

If you can find a good program that does what you want then #2 above will maximize your Return on Investment (ROI).  One caveat is that you'll need to convert all of your existing data, which may not be easy or even possible.  Make sure you investigate that before you buy anything.

While it may be the most expensive option up-front, hiring a competent database consultant is probably your best option if you need a truly custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at modern databases. If you're into Microsoft-based products, start with [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)

**EDIT**: However, since I understand that you're not a programmer yourself, you'd probably be better off having someone experienced look into your technical problem more deeply, like the other answer suggests.

Comment: Which of the actual specific issues raised in the question does this suggestion address? -1

Comment: -"no record of what was deleted" - you can use a transaction log

Comment: -"will not turn up a name in a search if cap's or punctuation is not entered exactly" - it's case insensitive by default, and punctuation can be handled with regular expressions if a little more is known abou the data

Comment: -"We'd like a more nimble program that we can access from more than one dedicated computer" - I wouldn't say it's nimble, but it IS a server

Comment: A transaction log will tell you the delete statement that deleted the record, but it won't give you the data that was deleted.

Comment: Jet/ACE is case insensitve by default, also (indeed, there's no way to make it case sensitive), so I don't understand what problem the original questioner is having. It's clearly not an Access/Jet/ACE problem.

Comment: An Access application can be accessed from multiple computers -- Jet/ACE is multiuser by default, so, again, it's ignorance on the part of the original questioner that's involved here, not the capabilities of Access/Jet/ACE.

Comment: So, to summarize: None of your points actually are in favor of SQL Server at all, since it doesn't resolve any of the issues any better than Access/Jet/ACE does.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server sounds like a viable alternative to your scenario.  If cost is a concern, you can always use SQL Server Express, which is free.  Full blown SQL Server provides a lot more functionality that might not be needed right away.  Express is a lot simpler as the number of features provided with it are much smaller.  With either version though you will have centralized store for your data and the ability to allow all transactions to be recorded in the transaction log.  Also, both have the ability to import data from an Access Database.

The newest version of SQL Server is 2008 R2

Comment: With due deference to *I'm not a techie, so keep in mind when answering*, the OP should be aware that SQL Server is not, out of the box, ideal for non-technical users. It typically provides the *data backend* for business software, while Access provides both a front- and back-end integrated with each other. Based on the question, SQL Server would probably only be part of the required solution.

Comment: This is a DREADFUL answer. It completely misses the point of all the questions being asked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to consider a front-end for your existing Access data store. Microsoft has yet to replace Access per se, but they do have a new tool that is a lot lower on the programming totem pole than some other options. Check out Visual Studio Lightswitch - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch.

It's fairly new (still in beta) but showing potential.  With it, just as with any Visual Studio project, you can connect to an MS Access datasource and design a front-end to interact with it.  The plus-side here is programming requirements are much lower than with straight-up Visual Studio (read: Wizards).

Comment: MS Access is a combination data store and front-end. You will need a solution, most-likely, for a new front-end with business logic built-in to suit your needs. Fundamentally at a basic-use-level, there is little difference between SQL Server, Express, or Access as a data-store for basic needs. On an enterprise-level, this is a different story.

Comment: SQL Server would be overkill (and costly). SQL Server Express will only work if you have a dedicated server-machine to host it on.  You will still need to write your own front-end, I agree with djacobson - it's only a part of the solution (the least important part).

Comment: In a small peer-to-peer office, SQL Server Express can run on a workstation. It's not ideal, but it's better than spending a lot of money on a dedicated server that isn't doing anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Given that replacing your Access DB will require some font-end programming, you may look into VistaDB.  It should allow your front end to be created in .NET with an XCopy database on the backend without requiring a server.  One plus is that it retains SQL Server syntax, so if you do decide to move to SQL Server you'll be one step ahead.

(Since you're not a techie and may not understand my previous statement, you might pass my answer on to the consultant/programmer/database guy who is going to do the work for you.)

http://www.vistadb.net/